# Input string was not in the correct form

Tags: c#, calculator

a C# beginner here. I've been following a guide on making a simple calculator. Everything worked fine 'till I added the point button. If I use the calculator to calculate basic integers there's no problem. However, when I add in the point button to calculate doubles with a decimal it gets all screwed up. Any ideas?

```
    // Above this are the numeric buttons, no problem with those

    private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnPoint.Text;
    }

    double total1 = 0; 
    double total2 = 0; 

    private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text); // Error comes here
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }

    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text); // And one time it came here
        txtDisplay.Text = total2.ToString(); 
        total1 = 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Well what's the value of `txtDisplay.Text`?

Comment: i think you need to trim the value before parsing.

Comment: It's the text box value so it's value is user input. It calculates fine if there's no decimals but once I add in a number with decimals it gives me the error.

Comment: @user2999898: A value such as? Please give the *exact string*, as well as which culture you're in.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the sad part of this question is, there are already 3 answers even they don't know _exact string_ and OP's culture.

Comment: @SonerGönül: Yup. There are a lot of assumptions here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string with a decimal point to a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/c-how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double)

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thanks for that, couldn't find that myself and it solved my issue. It was simply the fact that my computer was expecting a ',' instead of a '.'.

Answer (score 0):

Time ago I've made a simple calculator and for checking the input I have used regex(if you don't know what is a Regex take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

You can use this regex for checking the input: `^[0-9]{0,}([.,][0-9]{1,})?$` 
It allows:

```
0
10 
100
1,2
1.2
```

But not

```
.1
,1
 And all type of string
```

For using the regex in c# you must declare a Regex object. Before that you need to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`
Than use the regex is quite simple

```
Regex regex=new Regex(pattern);
if(regex.IsMatch(myTextBox.Text))
{//Do something
}
else{//Catch the error
}
```

If you want know more about regular expression take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `Double.Parse` use `Double.TryParse`.

```
private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double v = 0;
    if ( Double.TryParse(txtDisplay.Text.Trim(), out v)
    {
        total1 = total1 + v;
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid value
    }

}
```

Comment: [`Double.TryParse()` differs from the Double.Parse(String) method by returning a Boolean value that indicates whether the parse operation succeeded instead of returning the parsed numeric value.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) This doesn't resolve OP's problem as the parsing will still fail, it just returns a boolean instead of throwing an exception.