# C# string to decimal error

Tags: c#, string, decimal, formatexception

I'm having trouble with a very simple problem. Basically I'm taking a string, like "$30.00", and removing the '$' and then trying to convert it to a decimal. Although I keep getting an error stating that the string isn't in the correct format. Not sure what to do from here...

```
string freightstart = PostFregihtAmount.ToString();

freightstart = freightstart.TrimStart('$');

decimal freight = Decimal.Parse(freightstart);
```

I tried the following, per Alex Skiba's suggestion in the comments:

```
Decimal.Parse(freightstart, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is the error I receive upon debugging:

[image]

This is a plugin for our onsite CRM 2011 system and some fields that I have to reference on the quote form are currency fields. When I query the data they come back as string formats, hence the example "$30.00". Long story short I need to convert it to decimal so that I may do my tax solution.

Comment: What's an example of your input?

Comment: What is the value of `freightstart`?

Comment: Your code works for me with `"$30.00"` as the input...

Comment: No repro...  Check the value of `freightstart` using a debugger.  I suspect it is not what you think it is.

Comment: Probably you have localization issue here. Your regional settings are different from the input format. Try Decimal.Parse(freightstart, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
If it will help, read something about localization.

Comment: stupid to close the question as it's a real problem as @AlexSkiba stated

Comment: @addy2012, it might be a real problem, what what is the _question_? It boils down to "it doesn't work". We can't reproduce the issue with the input provided. I would have closed the question as "need more information", but Robert beat me to it.

Comment: @gunr2171 You can't, because your system has not the same culture information. On every German system it would fail, too.

Comment: @addy2012, you have already provided more information than the OP has. The OP needs to tell us what the input and environment is. Yes, we can suspect that is  the issue, but until the OP clarifies, this needs to stay closed.

Comment: I've tried the way @AlexSkiba stated and this is what I see during debugging [link](http://s2.postimg.org/8xahmymdl/Convert_Problem.png)

Comment: This is a simple, stupid problem but I can't seem to find the solution and @gunr2171 I am willing to provide anything that'll help me find the solution.

Comment: This is a plugin for our onsite CRM 2011 system and some fields that I have to reference on the quote form are currency fields. When I query the data they come back as string formats, hence the example "$30.00". Long story short I need to convert it to decimal so that I may do my tax solution.

Comment: @AkatsukiDiablo maybe you'll find the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double

Comment: See the “Copy exception detail to the clipboard” in your screen shot? Click that and put the message in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly allowing the decimal point when you parse the string, as well as the currency symbol (then you don't have to trim the `$` before parsing):

```
var freight = Decimal.Parse("$30.00",
              NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```