# Parsing a string to double with-/out using NumberStyles

Tags: c#

I am parsing a string number like 100.2543 to a double.

```
double actualValue = double.Parse(stringToParse, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
```

What is the difference to the same method but not using NumberStyles.Any? Is .Any by default?

```
double actualValue = double.Parse(stringToParse,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Comment: You can find the differences in MSDN. Why are you asking this, what do you want to get to know?

Comment: Possibly [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1354924/4519059) ;).

Comment: No, `NumberStyles.Any` is not the default. It can produce unexpected behavior, depending on your culture settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the difference to the same method but not using NumberStyles.Any? Is .Any by default?**

The difference, in your case, does not matter because 100.2543 this is just a natural double. .Any is just for basic double format.

But if it was something like €100.2543, now NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol would fit in this case. And there are other usages of NumberStyles on msdn documentation.

Pretty sure you get the idea, here is for complete documantation link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in MSDN?

> The s parameter is interpreted using a combination of the
>   NumberStyles.Float and NumberStyles.AllowThousands flags.