# Checking Regional and language setting in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I searched in "StackOverflow" but I couldn't find the answer.
My question:
I want to write a project with **asp.net** related to the numbers.
It need work with "Decimal" data (EX: 19.5), but in some countries like **canada** instead of **.** they use **,** that means if I write this code, I'll face with the error:

```
'in Canada
Dim A as Double =  Convert.ToDouble("19.5")  'Error
Dim A as Double =  Convert.ToDouble("19,5")  'OK

'in USA
Dim A as Double =  Convert.ToDouble("19.5")  'OK
Dim A as Double =  Convert.ToDouble("19,5")  'Error
```

I want my code work for all countries like USA which use 19.5 instead of 19,5.

- How can I check the **Regional and language setting** and accept 19.5 in **USA** and 19,5 in **Canada**.
- Or, How can I accept both in my program, without manipulating the string or using **Validator** or **try-catch**.

I appreciate you in advanced.

Comment: Actually there are a *lot* of duplicate questions - just pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the second parameter. Almost all parsing/formatting methods have an overload with an IFormatProvider parameter that can accept a specific culture. Also check the [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx), [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) methods that provide better control on how a string is parsed

Comment: Most .NET types have a Parse, TryParse method which provide much better parsing control. `Convert.ToDouble` for example, doesn't allow you to specify the number styles used while `Parse` allows you to specify scientific notation, hex numbers etc

Comment: I found myself the exact answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double)