# Calculations not correct

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing an app in C# in Visual Studio and when the button is pressed calculations aren't correct. Let me explain when numbers are `5 5 5` result is `70` but when numbers are `5.0 5.0 5` the result is `475`. It calculates numbers like they aren't decimals. If someone could help me that would be great. Thanks!

```
private void sum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double n1;
    double n2;
    double n3;


    if (double.TryParse(num1.Text.Replace(".", ","), out n1)
        && double.TryParse(num2.Text.Replace(".", ","), out n2)
        && double.TryParse(num3.Text.Replace(".", ","), out n3))
    {
        double sum = n1 * 4 + n2 * 5 + n3 * 5;
        String m = Convert.ToString(sum);
        sum1.Text = m;
    }
    else
    {
        sum1.Text = "Unesi sve!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to attach the debugger and inspect your variables.

Comment: Why do you think you should replace `.` by `,`?

Comment: Because when this happened in the last app that fixed it

Comment: double.TryParse("5,0") returns 50. You shouldn't be replacing the period with a comma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string with a decimal point to a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double)

Comment: Tried deleting that replace line fixed it. Thanks allot! Was i stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing `.` by `,`. Surely the `,` is `NumberGroupSeparator` in your current `CultureInfo`. Therefore `5,0` will be parsed as `50`:

```
50 * 4 + 50 * 5 + 5 * 5 == 475
```

Just dont replace `.` and your code will be fine:

```
if (double.TryParse(num1.Text, out n1) &&
    double.TryParse(num2.Text, out n2) &&
    double.TryParse(num3.Text, out n3)) ...
```

If you want use `,` as decimal separator:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";


if (double.TryParse(num1.Text, NumberStyles.Float, culture, out n1) &&
    double.TryParse(num2.Text, NumberStyles.Float, culture, out n2) &&
    double.TryParse(num3.Text, NumberStyles.Float, culture, out n3)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work just fine double.TryParse() handles commas and full stops:

```
private void sum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double n1;
    double n2;
    double n3;


    if (double.TryParse(num1.Text, out n1)
        && double.TryParse(num2.Text, out n2)
        && double.TryParse(num3.Text, out n3))
    {
        double sum = n1 * 4 + n2 * 5 + n3 * 5;
        sum1.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        sum1.Text = "Unesi sve!";
    }
}
```

**Update**

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ncFLxF)'s a small example that uses strings as input instead of textboxes