# C# cmd Console floating point number input

Tags: c#, console

When i want to read a floating point number (like `1.5`) the console gives me an *error*, but when i try `1,5` it *works*. How can I switch it so it works with '.'?

This is my code:

```
double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Where is the code? In which universe?

Comment: Try to use float or double data type

Comment: What's your current `Culture`?

Comment: Change the culture of your operating system? If you show us your code, perhaps we can give more input.

Comment: the code is double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
nothing special, just my console works with ',' and not with '.' and i want to change it.

Comment: This is called `Local Culture` (Locale) and it's set in windows... Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double

Comment: I've added your code _to your question_ for you. Please add relevant code to your question (not as a comment) in future.

Answer (score 3):

First, it's worth understanding that this has nothing to do with reading it from the console. `Console.ReadLine()` is just returning you a string - you'd get the same result if you hard-coded "1.5" as the value to parse.

The problem is that your machine's default culture uses `,` as the decimal separator rather than `.`, and `double.Parse` is using that default culture to parse the input.

You could either change the current culture as Sebastian says, or for a less invasive approach, you could pass the culture you want to use for parsing (typically the *invariant culture* in my experience, if you're not trying to use a specific user's culture) into the `double.Parse` method directly:

```
double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I'd personally shy away from changing the global culture unless you really, really want it to affect everything. Aside from anything else, if you specify the invariant culture everywhere you want to use it, it makes it very clear to everyone reading the code that you *do* want to use the invariant culture.

As an aside, if you want to keep the exact value the user entered, you may well want to use `decimal` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `CurrentCulture` does not support `.`.

You can try to change it to a culture that supports it, like `en-us`.

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-us");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now! But do i have to do it for every class?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *extracting a method* where you can hide the right *format selection* (you want `.` as a *decimal separator* and that;s why I suggest using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`) and *syntax check* (what if use put `bla-bla-bla`?):

```
 using System.Globalization;

 ... 

 public static double ReadDouble(string title = null) {
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title)) 
     Console.WriteLine(title);

   while (true) {
     // If syntax correct - i.e. "1.5" return parsed value: 1.5
     // If not keep on asking
     if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), 
                         NumberStyles.Any,             // accept any style
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, // invariant culture with . decimal
                         out var result))              // out var - C# 7.0 syntax
       return result;

     Console.WriteLine("Sorry, incorrect syntax, repeat the input");
   }
 }
```

And then you put

```
 double a = ReadDouble("Please, provide 'a'");

 ...

 double b = ReadDouble("And now, please, provide 'b'");

 double c = ReadDouble(); // Just read with no title
```