# ConvertToDouble when in French locale converting number incorrectly

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a number stored in the database as a float. In this case the number is 93.75

```cs
double localCultreResult;
double.TryParse(rs["CostClaim"].ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out localCultreResult);
if (rs["CostClaim"].ToString().Length > 0) {
    Cost.Value = localCultreResult;
};
```

I want the cost value to display as 93,75 when in French locale but instead the above gives me 9375,00

I have also tried all solutions here: [How do I parse a string with a decimal point to a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double)

All are converting 93.75 to 9375 when in French locale

Comment: What is the type of `rs["CostClaim"]`? You may be able to use `localCultreResult=(double)rs["CostClaim"];`

Comment: The type is float and the type of Cost is double

Comment: Try this `(double)rs["CostClaim"]`. Instead of trying to convert try to cast.

Comment: You will need to switch "test for non-empty" and "use the contents" - don't use empty contents

Comment: If the type of `rs["CostClaim"]` is `float` then you may need a double cast: first cast to float and then to double: `(double)(float)rs["CostClaim"]`

Comment: The double case throws an exception: System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: The cast will fail for a value of DbNull.Value - so first check for that (which presumably is the point of your Length check) and *only* when not null, cast to the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

If *CultureInfo.CurrentCulture* is french then *rs["CostClaim"].ToString()* will be parsed with a ',' as decimal point.

What do you think of:

```
if (double.TryParse(rs["CostClaim"].ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, 
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out double localCultreResult))
{
    Cost.Value = localCultreResult;
}
```