# Convert string to decimal without losing the period

Tags: c#, string, decimal

I have a numerical value in a string: **12.50000**

When i want to convert that string to decimal using Convert.ToDecimal() it deletes the period and it becomes **1250000**.

Is there a way to stop this? Because the final value is supposed to be 12.5, not 1250000.

Comment: Is it enough to just tell you to fix mistake in your code or you want to show it and get better help? See [mcve].

Comment: double.Parse("3.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) shoulddo it

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Test()
{
    var str = "12.50000";
    var y = decimal.TryParse(str, out var x);
    Debug.WriteLine(x);
}
```

why not using decimal.TryParse ?

Comment: That will still fail for the OP (while possibly working for you), for the same reason: the current applicable Culture

Comment: @HansKeﬆing. you are right. And we are developers , so we should consider all posiblities that we should.